# Best way to consume WCF Service from Access application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, ms-access-2010, clr

We have a WCF Service and now we are having to suppor tit in backward compatibility mode. One of the consumer turns out to be an Access Application. Now, I have personally never worked with Access and not sure if Access has a direct way to consume the WCF services. However, I came across following link:

http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2014/02/calling-wcf-service-from-stored.html?m=1

- Given the fact that I would be more comfortable working with SQL Server rather than doing any work in Access to do backward compatibility, I found this link as my best shot to backward compatibility.
- Are there any other ways that I can approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been asked and answered here:

[Calling WCF Service from MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942858/calling-wcf-service-from-ms-access)

In short, you can call a WCF service exposed via `WebHttpBinding` (simple HTTP) or `BasicHttpBinding` (SOAP/HTTP) using `XMLHttp` (for simple HTTP) or the `SOAP Toolkit` (for SOAP/HTTP).